# SharePoint 2013 Custom button to Delete a Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to delete the the Page with custom button. I have searched the the whole but found nothing. I have tried to find the ID of Delete button from Ribbon. But this also does not work.
I found a link but it does not help me.

[1] :https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19887/custom-delete-page-button

Anyone here know about the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised that no one have answer the question. Then I go deeper in Sharepoint and find a Solution to delete the page with custom Button or link.

So i decided to share with you guys. May be someone in future need this. I have achieve this through Javascript.

```
function deletePage() {
var url = document.location.pathname;
var urls = url.split("/");
var newurl = urls[1].concat("/", urls[2], "/", urls[3], "/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url);
var confirmDelete = confirm("Do you want to delete this news ??");
if (confirmDelete) {
folder.deleteObject();
}
//if (confirmDelete) {
//    window.location = "/" + newurl;
//}
context.executeQueryAsync(
function () {
if (confirmDelete) {
window.location = "/" + newurl;
}
}
);
}
```

And Just call this function onclick.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="deletePage()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Delete</a></li>
```

Well this is working perfect.

Thanks